# replacing multi line string with another multi line string using sed

Tags: sed, string

for eg.
input :

```
// copyright

package com.base

import com.base
import com.base
...
```

i want to replace the pattern "// copyright\n\n^package.*" with another string

i'm trying to do using

```
sed -e 's/.,^package/$(anotherString)/g' $text
```

Comment: How many empty lines between `// copyright` and `package ...` ? One or two ? Your example has one empty line in between but you're saying you want to replace `// copyright\n\npackage.*` which means two empty lines in between...

Answer (score 2):

### Using sed

Here is a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed '\|// copyright|,\|^package|{s/^package/Something\nElse/p;d}' file
Something
Else com.base

import com.base
import com.base
...
```

Did you want to remove all of the original `package` line?  If so, just a minor change is needed:

```
$ sed '\|// copyright|,\|^package|{s/^package.*/Something\nElse/p;d}' file
Something
Else

import com.base
import com.base
...
```

### Using awk

```
$ awk '/^\/\/ copyright/,/^package/{if (/^package/) print "Something\nElse"; next} 1' file
Something
Else

import com.base
import com.base
...
```

Comment: I get `"\|// copyright|,\|^pack ...": extra characters at the end of d command` error using the first `sed` command (bash on macOS) - any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @adamsfamily MacOS uses BSD tools instead of GNU.  That makes for a wide variety of minor yet annoying incompatibilities.  I don't have access to BSD tools to test this on but, based on past experience, I suspect that an extra semicolon is needed: try `sed '\|// copyright|,\|^package|{s/^package/Something\nElse/p;d;}' file`

Comment: thank you, it works like a charm! However, I just realized it hasn't entirely solved my problem, I have created another question if you are interested in checking it out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647980/replace-a-multi-line-c-variable-with-another-with-sed-or-awk - thanks!